Custom View with ViewModel not binding
I want to pass arguments (From,To) to my custom view. Inside this view I would like to bind my view model. When I bind view model to my view in code behind, the whole thing stops binding all together. What am I doing wrong?
View:
 <ContentView
    x:Name="this"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="clr-namespace:Microcharts.Maui;assembly=Microcharts.Maui"
    x:Class="LazyFit.Views.Mood.MoodChartView">

<VerticalStackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference this}">
    
    <Label  
        Text="Setable chart"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    <Label 
        Text="{Binding From}"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    <Label 
        Text="{Binding To}"
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    <Border Style="{StaticResource ClassicBorder}">
        <HorizontalStackLayout>
            <mc:ChartView Chart="{Binding ChartObject}" HeightRequest="150"/>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>
    </Border>

</VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>

Code behind:
using LazyFit.ViewModels.MoodViewModels;
using Microcharts;

namespace LazyFit.Views.Mood;

public partial class MoodChartView : ContentView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty FromProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(From), typeof(DateTime), typeof(MoodChartView), propertyChanged: OnFromToPropertyChanged);
    public static readonly BindableProperty ToProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(To), typeof(DateTime), typeof(MoodChartView), propertyChanged: OnFromToPropertyChanged);

    public DateTime From
    {
        get => (DateTime)GetValue(FromProperty);
        set => SetValue(FromProperty, value);
    }

    public DateTime To
    {
        get => (DateTime)GetValue(ToProperty);
        set => SetValue(ToProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnFromToPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var view = (MoodChartView)bindable;
        var viewModel = view.BindingContext as MoodChartViewModel;

        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            viewModel.FromDate = view.From;
            viewModel.ToDate = view.To;
            view.Chart = viewModel.ChartObject;
        }
    }

    public MoodChartView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MoodChartViewModel();
    }
}

ViewModel:
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using LazyFit.Classes;
using LazyFit.Services;
using Microcharts;
using SkiaSharp;

namespace LazyFit.ViewModels.MoodViewModels
{
    internal partial class MoodChartViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private DateTime _FromDate;
        partial void OnFromDateChanged(DateTime value)
        {
            LoadChart();
        }
 
        [ObservableProperty]
        private DateTime _ToDate;
        partial void OnToDateChanged(DateTime value)
        {
            LoadChart();
        }
 
        [ObservableProperty]
        private Chart _ChartObject;
 
        public MoodChartViewModel() 
        {      
            LoadChart();
        }
 
        private async void LoadChart()
        {
             //...some verified code
        }
    }
}

If I apply it like this no bind values are present in the view.

your BindingContext is set to an instance of your VM, but the two properties you mentioned are in the code-behind, not the VM

Yes that is the point. You set view and that should use viewmodel logic.

You should avoid overwriting BindingContext at the root level since a user will set it for their own bindings. There are some good techniques such as setting BindingContext at a child level, or, since you're using ContentView, you should investigate ControlTemplate and TemplateBinding.

That sounds way to complicated for my purpose. I just wanted to take advantage of INotifyProperty

Well it is complicated by the way you are implementing it. The BindingContext of the View is set to the viewmodel but you also set the BindingContext of the main VerticalStackLayout to the view instance. Now you can bind to view From and To property but not to any property of the viewmodel. There can be only ONE instance for BindingContext - there is no merge

Ok, so I can use custom view property, just not to bind them

You can bind to any you like ... but you have only one BindingContext {Binding PropertyName} - any other instance you have to set the source of the binding {Binding Source=..., Path=PropertyName}
